# How can I synchronize my front cam preview orientation with the device orientation?

Tags: java, android, camera, orientation

I use a surfaceview to preview the front camera view in my app to let the user take a picture of his/her face. I want the preview's orientation to synchronize with the device orientation, so when the user rotates the device, the camera preview rotates as well. The following is my surfaceCreated:

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  camera = openFrontFacingCamera();
  if (camera != null) {
    try {
      camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
      camera.setPreviewDisplay(cameraPreview.getHolder());
      camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } else {
    myActivity.finish();
  }
}
```

This rotates the preview when the device is rotated, but not the right way. If I hold the phone in portrait mode, it's ok with this code. but in both landscape modes the preview is 90 degrees off. How can I make it so the preview is always straight up? (except for reverse portrait, I don't think the phone rotates to that anyway).
I don't care if the image is mirrored, a lot of people seem to have problems with that, but it's not relevant for my app. I just want it to always have the top side, you know... on top :D.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the line :-
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Then use the Matrix class for the rotation or for proper orientation.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
if (cameraPlugin.getCurrentCamId() == MyCameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
    matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
matrix.postRotate(90);
```

And after this,use this matrix object with bitmap like below before setting it on surfaceView or canvas :-

mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap , 0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);